# How to get searchString in ASP.NET with jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, ashx

front-end:

```
$("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
    url: "jqGridHandler.ashx",
    mtype: 'post',
    datatype: 'json',
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['CardNumber', 'CardType', 'CardGrade', 'CanUseMoney', 'MemberName'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'CardNumber', index: 'CardNumber', width: 150, search: true,
            searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq']}},
        { name: 'CardType', width: 150},
        { name: 'CardGrade', width: 150 },
        { name: 'CanUseMoney', width: 150 },
        { name: 'MemberName', width: 150, search: true,
            searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq']} }
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: 'CardNumber',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'asc',
    caption: 'card',
    pager: $("#pager")
}).navGrid('#pager',
    { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchtext: "search" });
```

jqGridHandler.ashx:

```cs
HttpRequest request = context.Request;

string _searchsrt = request["searchString"];
```

I would like to get `searchString` in "jqGridHandler.ashx", but I found it is ""
how to do? can any one help me out? tks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HttpRequest` to get the parameters which send jqGrid. The code can be about the following:

```cs
public class jqGridHandler: IHttpHandler {
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        // get parameters sent from jqGrid
        string numberOfRows = request["rows"];
        string pageIndex = request["page"];
        string sortColumnName = request["sidx"];
        string sortOrderBy = request["sord"];
        string isSearch = request["_search"];
        string searchField = request["searchField"];
        string searchString = request["searchString"];
        string searchOper = request["searchOper"];

        // construct the JSON data based on the 
        string output = BuildJQGridResults (
            Convert.ToInt32 (numberOfRows),
            Convert.ToInt32 (pageIndex),
            Convert.ToInt32 (totalRecords),
            isSearch!= null && String.Compare (isSearch, "true",
                                               StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0,
            searchField,
            searchString,
            searchOper
        );

        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        response.Write (output);
    }
```

It's important that the parameters `searchString`, `searchField` and `searchOper` will be set only if the user uses [single searching dialog](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching) (you don't set `multipleSearch: true` option). For the [Advanced Searching dialog](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching) the parameter [filters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching#options) will be used. If the user don't used any searching dialog the corresponding parameters (`searchString`, `searchField`, `searchOper` or `filters`) will be `null`.